# Angular 9 Global Alert not being triggered (nested outlet)

Tags: angular, global, nested-routes

I am following this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/28/angular-9-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#account-register-component-ts) that has implemented a global Alert class and service to handle all erros in the app. I'm trying to implement this alert on the login component only, but the error is not being triggered and Im kind of lost because all of this has to do with nested outlets so i'm not sure what is goin on

The alert Service (all with bootstrap)

```
 private subject = new Subject<Alert>()
  private defaultId = 'default-alert';


  onAlert(id = this.defaultId): Observable<Alert> {
    return this.subject.asObservable().pipe(filter(x => x && x.id === id));
  }

alert(alert: Alert) {
  alert.id = alert.id || this.defaultId;
  this.subject.next(alert);
}

clear(id = this.defaultId) {
  this.subject.next(new Alert({ id }));
}

  success(message: string, options?: any) {
    this.alert(new Alert({ ...options, type: AlertType.Success, message }));
  }

  error(message: string, options?: any) {
    this.alert(new Alert({ ...options, type: AlertType.Error, message }));
  }
    //other methods identical for info, etc
```

The alert component TS:

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id = 'default-alert';
  @Input() fade = true;

  alerts: Alert[] = [];
  alertSubscription: Subscription;
  routeSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.alertSubscription = this.alertService.onAlert(this.id)
      .subscribe(alert => {
        if (!alert.message) {
          this.alerts = this.alerts.filter(x => x.keepAfterRouteChange);

          this.alerts.forEach(x => delete x.keepAfterRouteChange);
          return;
        }

        this.alerts.push(alert);
        console.log(this.alerts)

        if (alert.autoClose) {
          setTimeout(() => this.removeAlert(alert), 3000);
        }
      });

    this.routeSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.alertService.clear(this.id);
      }
    });
  }
```

And some other methods about setting up bootstrap classes, and onDestroy lifeCycle

Now, this is the Alert Class HTML. The "p" tag displaying "alert works!" is visible all over the app(child routes), but not in the login component when I catch the error upon subscription

```
    <p>Alert Works!</p> 
    <div *ngFor="let alert of alerts" class="{{cssClass(alert)}}">
        <a class="close" (click)="removeAlert(alert)">&times;</a>
        <span [innerHTML]="alert.message"></span>
    </div>
```

And My Nav-bar, where I have the nested outlet and the reference to the alert component:
      
        ...

```
<div class="container">
    <app-alert></app-alert>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

The implementation on the Login Component:

```
onSubmit() {

    this.alertService.clear();


    if (this.loginForm.invalid) return;




    this.auth.login(credentials)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(data => {
        let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
        this.alertService.success('Login successful', { keepAfterRouteChange: true });
        this.router.navigate(['/home' || returnUrl], { relativeTo: this.route });
      }, error => {
        this.alertService.error(error);
        console.log(error)
        //this.loginError=true;
      })

  }
```

Problably this has to do with the routing configuration? I hide the menu bar with routing. This is my main routing file:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: NavbarComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule, canLoad: [AuthGuardService], canActivate: [AdminAuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: RegisterComponent, canDeactivate: [EditUserGuardService] },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]

  },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },

];
```

At this point I cant figure out why the alarm isn't triggered. The code seems correct to me, I can't see any logic error on this implementation...Can someone take a look? Thank you

Comment: in which component you have <app-alert></app-alert> ?

Comment: that tag is being called above the router outlet, right bellow the navbar

Comment: so its in the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move `<app-alert></app-alert>` in app.component.html

Comment: It doesnt work because I have a core module the is like the app module. All the components are in there, including the navbar

Comment: you have to place it where your main router outlet is.

Comment: export alert component from coremodule.

Comment: it worked, thanks! The thing missing was to export the alert component and call it in the appc.component like you said

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is because you have a variable that verifies the `routes`, and every time it changes it eliminates the added alerts. I recommend you to eliminate the `routeSubscription` variable and everything related to it in your `AlertComponent`.